# magento 2 rename pub folder to public_html

Tags: magento2, migration

I'm using cpanel that cannot change the default document root.
can I just rename the `pub` folder to `public_html` like **laravel** `public` folder ?

the application already ran with `/index.php` executed not `/pub/index.php` this causing many missing image url from migrated data `/media` not `/pub/media`.

Thanks

Comment: no.. pub folder have a all date `static`, `image` in Magento 2 pun folder is main

Answer (score 0):

If your web root is /public_html then you could assign your web root to /public_html/pub instead of just /public_html. Magento 2 will still function properly.

Comment: you are right, my aplication already ran with that way, but the image link will be broken on product description because I need add "/pub" before "/media" in database manually.

Comment: If you have /pub/ as the web root then you wouldn't need to add it before /media/ in the database or anywhere else because as far as the web server is concerned the location is just "/media/" and not "/pub/media/"

Comment: that's what I'm asking here because I can't change the default document root to pub folder from cpanel. the default document root is public_html

Comment: If the pub/media is the problem then try creating a symlink to pub/media in the public_html folder called "media".  That would give a structure of public_html/media -> public_html/pub/media.